# Deploying Ghost 0.4.2 to Azure Site using Git Deploy

Tags: node.js, git, azure, npm, ghost-blog

I'm trying to upgrade my really simply ghost test site to the latest version of Ghost 0.4.2. I've followed the upgrade instructions on their website and am able to run the upgraded version of the project locally.

When I try to push the upgrade version to my azure instance using the GIT Deploy process I'm getting the following error log. Can anyone shed some light on what's going wrong. My best guess is that their is something wrong with the new version of sqlite.

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'iisnode.yml'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28.
Selected node.js version 0.10.28. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite3
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
Failed exitCode=50, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.28\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.9\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
npm ERR! error rolling back  sqlite3@2.2.0 { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node']
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v11-win32-ia32\\node_sqlite3.node' }
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\Release\\node-v11-win32-ia32\\node_sqlite3.node' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
 npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.28\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.9\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\Release\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the file in question `...\node_sqlite3.node` being locked. When faced with the same error I've restarted Azure Website and redeployed, it worked the second time.

I know, not exactly a root cause solution, but will get you up and running if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that my Git repo had the node_modules folder included so this was being deployed along with the code. This isn't needed - Kudu will build the dependencies at deploy time.

Try removing the node_modules folder from your repo, and stick an entry in your `.gitignore` so that it doesn't get re-added. You'll also want to do the same for your `Ghost.db` and any other bits of content that shouldn't get replaced at deploy time.

Comment: Both `node_modules` and `*.db` are in .gitignore already. Not sure whether they were there at the time of the response, they're there now at least in the official `stable` branch.